# About $(0,1/2)$ representations

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, lie-algebra

While studying representations of Lorentz group, we get the generators to be $J_{i}$  - rotations and $K_{i}$ - boosts. We define $N_{i}^+$ and $N_{i}^-$ operators and these operators obey the same Lie algebra as the $SO(3)$. Hence we conclude that we use these representations for $N_{i}^+$ and $N_{i}^-$.  If we look at these representations, how can we make $N_{i}^+$ and $N_{i}^-$ act on different dimension vectors, which we do while studying $(0,1/2)$ or $(1/2,0)$ representations?

Did I get the ideas right? I am an undergraduate, so please don't use advanced terms.

In case, 
$N_{i}^+$ and $N_{i}^-$ are  $J_{i}$ + i$K_{i}$ and  $J_{i}$ - i$K_{i}$ apart from some constant factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors in representation $(0,1/2)$ can be seen as a tensor product of vectors in $(0)$ and $(1/2)$, where $(0)$ is a one dimensional space and $(1/2)$ is a two-dimensional space, i.e., a spinor. The operator $N_i^+$ is actually $N_i^+ \otimes I$, and $N_i^-$ is $I \otimes N_i^{-}$, and they act on vectors $v^+ \otimes v^-$.

Comment: isn't (0) a one dimensional vector space ? It has dimension (2j+1).

Comment: Sorry for mistakes. I have corrected it.

Comment: Anyway, that's not what I wanted to ask. So (0,1/2) representations act on 3 component vector space, where $N_{i}^+$ acts on the first two components and the third one doesn't change under Lorentz transformations as it (0). Have I got it right? So we neglect writing the third component and say the right spinor has 2 complex components.

Comment: The dimension of the direct product of a $m$-dimensional space and a $n$-dimensional space is $m \times n$, not $m+n$. For example, if the base vector of $(0)$ is $e_1$ and the base vector of $(1/2)$ is $j_1$ and $j_2$, the base vector for (0,1/2) will be $e_1 \otimes j_1$ and $e_1 \otimes j_2$. Direct product is not direct sum.

Comment: But aren't direct sum and direct product same for finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: I should use the term 'tensor product' for strictness. Please check [Direct Sum vs. Direct Product vs. Tensor Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334965/direct-sum-vs-direct-product-vs-tensor-product/1335350)